# Yii - как сохранить mvc?

Tags: mvc, yii

Есть сайт на Yii, который состоит из разных контроллеров, каждый контроллер отвечает за свою работу. Начал переписывать "Карточку пользователя" - в которой отображается вся информация по многим контроллерам.

**Как было раньше:**

Некий контроллер User загружал всю необходимую информацию, которую нужно было вывести, и вызывал свою view.

**Как хочу сделать:**

Некий контроллер User загружает минимум информации по пользователю, передает своему view, а она в нужном месте отображает некие блоки из разных контроллеров (за загрузку данных отвечать должны контроллеры).

**Вопрос:**

1. В правильную ли сторону я думаю (или это плохая идея)?
2. При отображении блока у контроллера запускать его action или сразу view?
3. Как можно сделать render у action контроллера?

Comment: эээ а почему у вас рендерингом вообще контроллер хочет заняться ? поставка данных - модель, а контроллер тот кто снаружи получил данные и решает какие модели опросить и какие вьюхи вызвать... вьюха же пусть **на основе полученных данных** вызывает виджеты рендерера. Вообще хороший совет - отправлять во вьюху только те данные которые вы готовы (не против, по соображениям безопасности) передать в сыром виде клиенту. И кроме как рендерить во вьюхе ничего нельзя.

Comment: @eicto т.е. нужно в контроллере опрашивать другие контроллеры, и загружать нужные модели с данными? )

Просто сейчас в одном контроллере в обход всех фильтров других контроллеров идет загрузка данных (фильтры тупо продублированы). И на уровне интуиции мне это не нравится...

Comment: ничего в контроллере не надо опрашивать, в нем надо опрашивать модели. причем тут другие контроллеры ? (первый раз слышу о такой идее)

Comment: может то что вы хотите называется HMVC ?

Comment: @eicto похоже у меня сейчас каша в голове )Спасибо, вроде понял, что вы хотели сказать.

А вообще, хотел получить область, которая бы не работала бы с другими моделями, а просто загружал нужный блок. Т.е. к примеру личная страничка пользователя в ХэшКоде, состоит из:

- блок контактной информации;
- блок вопросов;
- блок меток;
- и т.д.

как я понял под каждый блок - своя модель, и отображается это все в одной view. А если появиться новый блок? - надо передавать новую модель и ее отображать.

----

ааа) получается можно* из view рендерить другое view передавая ему модель..?

Comment: @eicto можно еще один вопрос?: для одного пользователя нужно отображать ссылку, для другого нет (по ролям) - как в этом случае сделать логику?

Comment: @IVsevolod то что вы привели в последнем комментарии называется виджетами. Почитайте про виджеты, возможно в голове у вас всё наладится ;) У меня в начале изучения Yii была схожая каша.

Comment: @andrew68, да да. Yii для начала изучения MVC сложноват по отношению например к ZendFramework

Answer (score 1):

Если только это Ajax то да "условно можно сделать отдельные запросы". Если php то в чем проблема, вызвать метод из класса?